# perl extract/match last floating point number from string

Tags: regex, perl, floating-point

Need to extract last floating point number from the string below and save into a variable.

```
F791775                (6010.822, 4396.812) (6013.341, 4405.921)   9.451
```

Expected output: `9.451`

Used the following regex

```
my $inj_spacing = $line =~ m {(\d+.\d+)}x;
```

but this extracts= `1`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You get the number 1 as a result because your regex is in scalar context (because the left-hand side argument is a scalar). It is merely a true value, denoting that the regex matched.

What you want is to impose a list context, which can be done by adding parentheses:

```
my ($inj_spacing) = $line =~ m {(\d+\.\d+)}x;
```

(You also need to escape the period, as tools said)

Also, of course, this will match the first possible time, so you need to anchor it to the end:

```
my ($inj_spacing) = $line =~ m {(\d+\.\d+)\s*$}x;
```

I added `\s*` to account for optional whitespace. This is not recommended if trailing whitespace indicates missing data in the last column (e.g. with csv data). But for an informal type of text matching, it will prevent false mismatches.

Comment: won't that match the first float 6010.822? I think there should be and end-of-sting anchor: m/(\d+\.\d+)$/...also for correctness you should escape the '.' operator

Comment: @Davs Yes, I just corrected the first thing I saw was wrong. I have now fixed everything.

Comment: Thanks TLP and Dave. And thanks all who gave their thoughts to this. Solution (by TLP) works good. Appreciate this forum.

Comment: @user3182647 You're welcome. If your question has been answered, you can mark an answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

If your string always has that format, another option is to use `split` to get the last fp number:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = 'F791775                (6010.822, 4396.812) (6013.341, 4405.921)   9.451';
my $inj_spacing = ( split ' ', $str )[-1];
print $inj_spacing;
```

Output:

```
9.451
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks TLP and Dave. And thanks all who gave their thoughts to this. Solution (by TLP) works good. Appreciate this forum.

Comment: @user3182647 - Please consider checking "Accept" by TLP's answer if it's working for you.